# An order endomorphism on a complete lattice has a fixed point

Tags: order-theory

I am trying to show the claim in the title. I have made some progress, which I will outline below:

Denote the complete lattice $(X, \leq)$, and an arbitrary order endomorphism on it $\phi$. I propose that, given the set $A = \{ x \in X \mid x \leq \phi(x) \}$ (whose existence is assured by $\bot X$), $\vee A = \phi(\vee A)$ (the join operation being acceptable because $X$ is complete). To this end, **I want to show**:

- $\vee A \leq \phi(\vee A)$
- $\phi(\vee A) \leq \vee A$.

Unfortunately, I got lost very quickly after that. I have noted a few relationships but that's about as far as I've gotten. (I use $a$ to represent an arbitrary member of $A$.)

1. $a \leq \vee A$ by definition of join
2. $\phi(a) \leq \phi(\vee A)$ by (1) and the order preserving nature of $\phi$
3. $a \leq \phi(a)$ by construction of $A$
4. $\phi(a) \leq \vee \phi[A]$ by definition of join
5. $\phi(\vee A) = \vee \phi[A]$ by... I'm actually not sure about this, haha. Might need to prove this as a lemma, if I end up using it.

I'd be very grateful if anyone could help me with this proof. Please let me know if you need anything more from me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $u=\bigvee A$. Then $x\le u$ for each $x\in A$, so $x\le\varphi(x)\le\varphi(u)$, and it follows that $\varphi(u)$ is an upper bound for $A$ and hence that $u\le\varphi(u)$ (since $u$ is the *least* upper bound of $A$). But then $\varphi(u)\le\varphi\big(\varphi(u)\big)$, so $\varphi(u)\in A$. Can you finish it from here?

Comment: Because $\phi(u) \in A$ and $u$ is the least upper bound of $A$, $\phi(u) \leq (u)$. ? Also, can I ask whether you knew that proof beforehand or came up with that on the spot? I'm still in the phase where I'm awed by people solving proofs quickly, haha.

Comment: @JohnDoeVsJoeSchmoe: Exactly. I have seen it before, but I had to think about it a little.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to this site, hence the panic edits

Comment: @JohnDoeVsJoeSchmoe: Not a problem!

Comment: Can I ask a very general question about working with lattices? I know that the right way to visualize them is as diamonds, but when I'm actually working with them, like trying to think about functions on them or subposets of them, I have a really hard time unless I think about them as a chain. This seems like a problem. Do you have any suggestions?

Ancillary question: is the little claim $\phi(\vee A) = \vee \phi[A]$ correct? If so, is it correct on all posets? Just complete lattices? What's the deal there? You don't need to go into detail, just hoping for a yes/no answer

Comment: @JohnDoeVsJoeSchmoe: I’ve not actually worked with them all that much, but I tend to see them as roughly diamond-shaped but with all sorts of chains running through them. \\ Not necessarily: take $\Bbb R$ as your lattice, and let $\varphi(x)=x$ if $x<0$ and $\varphi(x)=x+1$ if $x\ge 0$. Then $$\varphi\left(\bigvee A\right)=\varphi(0)=1\ne 0=\bigvee\varphi[A]\;.$$

Comment: I see. Thank you so much for your time! I'm very grateful for your help.

Comment: @JohnDoeVsJoeSchmoe: You're very welcome.